# Want to solve a riddle where I convert Hex data to string data but not able to use that string data propely

Tags: encryption, hex, png, decode

I am trying to solve a riddle in which data is given in the form of hex data i think..

```
89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000001D0000000708020000007BBCD1A5000000017352474200AECE1CE90
000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000EC301C76FA8640000001874455874536F
667477617265007061696E742E6E657420342E302E36FC8C63DF000001AA4944415428534D513DC8416118BD7E4A1
9180C0665A0582C8C7E22DF20C5480A130629060CF29792C16CB06293C82283C2F0C562540693C94F297F2983FB9D
EBF9BEDB77A673CE7DEE799FF3BE0CFB81C160904824C4098542C1E17098CDE672B90C399D4E9D4EA740208846A39
BCD2693C9300CF3F5079A29168B56ABD5E572B5DBEDDF5C954A85B9D3E944D2EBF5D66AB5DBEDF67EBF5BADD6EBF5
1A8D4676BB1D9F7ABD9EDFEF877FBFDFE3F1782E97BB5EAFF0B1473A9D063F1C0E1A8D86CB1D8FC7D8CBE3F1341A0
DC8C964A2502840FE83CF050987C3642693C96AB54A1C558810B8DC4824321C0E178B85CD66836C369BD80244A7D3
A194DBED7E3C1E8893CBE5E804743A1DEE57964DA552F57A1D64B7DB994C2632095CAE4C260B8542C160502A95AED
7EBC160100804E05F2E97E3F1882054E6F7DDEFF770CEE73378369BA5DCE7F3899B04E1C174BBDD582CF6FD01162F
954AD84EA9542E974B9A108BC5FF7301AD564B2F91CFE729174033BC1BF17EBFCFF87CBEF97C4E7ABBDDEAF57A90D
96C66341A3FA519FE5AD56A35A44824C2D99F71B652A9F0B9ABD5CA62B1604028142612891FA2F7838B729D41E800
00000049454E44AE426082
```

When I convert this data to string it shows something like PNG file but now I am not able to view it .
Help me on this.

The converted file looks like..

```
PNG


IHDR{¼Ñ¥sRGB®ÎéFtÔð¿ÆP0ì0ì0vú@DUE6ftwarepaint.net 4.0.6ücßªIDAT(SMQ=ÈAa½~JÀfZÈÇâ-òT¡0b`Ï)y,Ë)<(</V%@i<òò?¹
ëù¾Ûw¦sÎ}îyó¾ûÁ`H$Ä BÁápÍær¹9NN§@ F£    ¼Òi<Ï?Py¢hµj½^W+]¾ÝõÉT¨[>M.¿]f«]¾ßgëõºÝn¿Fv»z½ßï¿ßãñx.»^¯ð±G:?ËÇØËãñ4ÜJ%è<ðP|6Bi<«T¡ÅXÄC!Àáx¸\Öh6Ãi½$J}¡Ûí~<Ëåèt:îWM¥Rõzd·ÛL&2  \®L&BÁ`P*®
~¼Nòé~?No}Þÿwîs7iº]Î8°NK½ÕÏoÐbJØN©T.KÅÿs­VK/Ïç)@3¼ñ~¿Ïø|¾ù|Nz»Ýêõz
ÆcA£úQå­V£ZDL-÷e*½\¦+Ba(ú/x8·)ÔIEND®B`
```

Comment: How are you "converting this data to string"? Are you using a specific character encoding? If you suspect it's a PNG image, can you write the raw bytes into a file and open that file with a PNG viewer? Have you looked at the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) to see if it follows that format?

Comment: I am using an online convertor.Yes I have trie it to open it in PNG viewer but not able to open it.

Comment: I just need to get text out of the hex data..

Comment: Binary data is not text and you cannot treat it as such. Also, what's the programming problem here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because riddles are not programming questions.